# Android Emulator's Audio stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, audio

I'm using Eclipse and the Android Emulator on my Mac.

My app has a background audio. It was working before but today when I started Eclipse again, there was no audio.

I tried to delete/recreate new virtual devices from API level 15 to API level 18 but it didn't work.

There is no error in the logcat and the app runs fine.. apart from the fact that there is no audio.

Mac's audio is working. I can hear songs on it.

The avd has the volume bar set to high but for some reason there is no audio.

I am not using snapshot, I am using GPU and I did upgrade my Android SDK manager to the latest API level recently.. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Check on real device...

Comment: Audio works on a real device.. I haven't changed the code. I just fired up eclipse and the audio isn't working on the emulator.

Comment: Does any other audio apart from your current app are playing on the Emulator???

Comment: @sai I tried playing a youtube video and a song from soundcloud.com but it didn't play the audio. It seems to be a problem with the emulator as opposed to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more way to solve your issue might be using new `Genymotion Android Emulator` , it is available for Mac too and it is faster than `Google's Android Emulator`. I have just tested and audio working fine on Windows, I am using latest `Android SDK Tools r22.0.5`

Comment: I'm trying it out now. Hope it works. Although they only have a preview version of 4.3

Comment: I tried it and my audio worked! Thanks a lot! Plus Geny is very fast, almost as if it is a native app. I loved using it. Normally AVD is ver slow and an exercise in patience.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solve it by going to Genymotion
and slecting the emulator then setting->ADB->use custom Android Sdk tools

Answer (score 0):

some Way to solveing
1-Check your setting of emulator for `hw.audioInput=yes`
2-Download again your platform and make new emulator
3-Download again last sdk and replace
4-Try using different VM with different versions of sdk

Comment: Apparently that file did have the hw.audioInput=yes already. Still there's no sound.

Comment: So .Check other way!! may Help you.

Comment: I'm currently downloading the SDK. This audio problem started after I downloaded the API level 18.

Comment: Is Enable your Emulator sound in emulator??

Comment: ?? I've made sure that the sound level isn't set to 0 in the emulator, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Ok.I dont know may this is a problem in new sdk ! so download other sdk may solve problem. if other sdk version solve problem this is a bug in new sdk else your computer has a problem.Or may new sdk not good for your sound card

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to re install the eclipse and android sdk.

Here are some links which may help you

[MediaPlayer no longer working on the emulator since r10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259849/mediaplayer-no-longer-working-on-the-emulator-since-r10/8262747#8262747)

[Can not get any hear any audio from Android SDK emulator launched from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881743/can-not-get-any-hear-any-audio-from-android-sdk-emulator-launched-from-eclipse)

[Can't hear sound Android Simulator Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176403/cant-hear-sound-android-simulator-mac)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the support libraries that you might have missed while downloading the API 18..

Try installing the support libraries too and then create a new AVD and check it should work.

Comment: just to add to the answer.. The support library is available in the SDK manager

Comment: Hi Glen, I checked, the android support library rev 18 is installed. Plus the sound doesn't work even on older sdks, where it was previously working.

Comment: Hi, then definitely the best approach would be to uninstall the API 18 installed and backup all other API's and reinstall the entire eclipse along with the SDK and then put the API's back in the specific folders so that they are recognized by the sdk manager. and at last re-install the API 18 to give it a try

Answer (score 0):

in linux (Arch linux) just add `-audio alsa` switch on target tab(Run configuration)

that's work for me fine

if not work you may try `-audio oss`